Postgresql/psycopg2: how to start a transaction, pause for manual inspection of the DB, and commit if satisfied?
Looks like the default transaction isolation level in psycopg2 doesn't persist anything in the DB until it is committed.
I'm automating some DB operations and the script will pause for me to inspect the DB manually. But the uncommitted changes don't show in the DB.
In plain SQL I could begin; a transaction, execute the insert/upsert/delete, inspect the DB, and commit or rollback.
How can I emulate this flow in Python with psycopg2?

Reading Transactions Control would be a good start.

This seems like a pretty severe anti-pattern. I would suggest one of two approaches: 1. Load a staging table that you can inspect, and then copy records from that table into your final table and/or 2. See if there is a way to automate those checks within the transaction so that it will rollback if a check is invalid
